# Function to add and sum even numbers

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I wrote this piece of code to find even values in a dictionary and output the sum. For some reason, I think the code is only getting the first value in the dictionary. A little insight would be much appreciated:

```
def sumEven(dct):
    total = 0
    for val in dct.values():
        if (val % 2 == 0):
            total += val
            return total
        
user_dct = {'hero':6,
            'battlefields':4,
            'villains':'everyone',
            'outcome':1,
            'possibilities':999}

sumEven(user_dct)
```

Comment: Hint: do you want to return in the first iteration of the for loop on an even value?

Comment: :D over an hour of going over and over this!! It works!!

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when you try to test if `'everyone'` is even?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I want the code to avoid anything that's not an int or float, so I'm testing for that capability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sumEven(dct):
    total = 0
    for val in dct.values():
        if isinstance(val, int): #Filter out string
            if (val % 2 == 0):
                total += val
    return total
```

Output
`10`